# Static dictionary type variable declaration in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have been trying to declare a static dictionary within a "struct". However, I could not achieve this. It gives me **"Type 'BagItem' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"** .

And my code is here:

```
struct StaticBag {

    static var bag: Dictionary<BagItem, Array<BagItem>> = Dictionary<BagItem, Array<BagItem>>()

//    static func AddMainItem(item: BagItem)
//    {
//        self.bag[item] = Array<BagItem>()
//    }
}
```

'BagItem' in the code is my another global class.
What is the right and best way to declare this variable ?

Thank you for your answers

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says, the issue is that your custom `BagItem` type doesn't conform to the `Hashable` protocol. Dictionary keys need to be hashable, since dictionaries use the hash values to look up entries quickly.

What does `BagItem` look like? Is there a unique property that is already hashable? If so, you can add `Hashable` conformance by adding a `hashValue` property and implementing the `==` operator:

```
class BagItem : Hashable {
    var uniqueID: Int = 0
    var hashValue: Int { return uniqueID.hashValue }
}

func ==(lhs: BagItem, rhs: BagItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.uniqueID == rhs.uniqueID
}
```